# How to set button frame for different screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, frame

I have button to display from x origin 700 or so. It's showing in iPadMini, but when i run the app in normal iPad it's not showing.

I have four button to display. In iPad i need display below sizes.

```
[back_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,40,40)];

 [save setFrame:CGRectMake(195, 10, 40, 40)];

  [camera setFrame:CGRectMake(385, 10, 40, 40)];

 actionshet setFrame:CGRectMake(575, 10, 40, 40)];


 In iPadMini need to display same buttons in below sizes:




[back_btn setFrame:CGRectMake(30,10,40,40)];

 [save setFrame:CGRectMake(215, 10, 40, 40)];

 [camera setFrame:CGRectMake(405, 10, 40, 40)];

 actionshet setFrame:CGRectMake(605, 10, 40, 40)];
```

Comment: Use AutoLayout or autoresize

Comment: Using self.view.frame.origin.x also helps but you should also consider where you are setting frame for your button. Means in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Set a macro for device width and height like -

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

And give frame of button like this -

```
CGRectMake(SCREEN_WIDTH*0.05, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.05, SCREEN_WIDTH*0.90, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.08);
```

Comment: what my code is doing is getting the device width height in macro (no matter which device you run it) and setting the frame of in percentage of that width and height. e.g if width is 100 than x origin will be 5% of width that is 5 px and if width is 200 than 10px. give it a try hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayout in your interface file of add this code

```
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 10, 40, 40)];
```